# I am unable to use my pear packages on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, pear

I am trying to use the pear package for Net_SMTP but I cannot get any pear package to run with php. I went through the install instructions and I am able to use `pear` commands from the command line, and I also install Net_SMTP without any issues.

However it looks like all of the packages are being installed to `/home/user/pear/share/pear` and this directory is not being found and used. I used `phpinfo();` to see what was going on and found the loaded `php.ini` file as well as the `include_path`. The include path is pointing to `/usr/share/pear` which is empty, and `/usr/share/php` which does have a folder called `PEAR`, however this folder does not include any packages.

I then used `pear config-get php_dir` to see where the pear packages are going and I found them installed at `/home/user/pear/share/pear`. I changed the `php.ini` file that `phpinfo();` said was loaded, but when I refreshed the page these values were not displayed.

So I am somewhat new to Linux and this all has me very confused. Should I move the location of pear package installed to the php directory? Or would it be better to leave them in the user directory as this was the default? Why didn't changing the loaded configuration file according to `php_info()` yield any changes?

Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

**EDIT:** I included the installation options when using the go-pear.phar file, should these be changed?

```
1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : /home/user/pear
2. Temporary directory for processing            : /tmp/pear/install
3. Temporary directory for downloads             : /tmp/pear/install
4. Binaries directory                            : /home/user/pear/bin
5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : /home/user/pear/share/pear
6. Documentation directory                       : /home/user/pear/docs
7. Data directory                                : /home/user/pear/data
8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : /home/user/pear/cfg
9. Public Web Files directory                    : /home/user/pear/www
10. Tests directory                               : /home/user/pear/tests
11. Name of configuration file                    : /home/user/.pearrc

1-11, 'all' or Enter to continue:
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing `php.ini`, you have to restart your web server (apache).

Answer (score 0):

You nead to install php-net-smtp package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-net-smtp
```